# Blank array serialized when serializing to XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, serialization

I am trying to serialize two List objections to SQL Server.

This is my serialization code:

```
public static string SerializeToXml<T>(this T value)
{
    var writer = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

When the following property is serialized and then saved, everything looks fine:

```
this.IPHostList = liveHostIps.SerializeToXml<List<string>>();
```

But when I try this with a custom class, I do not get any data.

```
this.MyClassList = MyClassContainer.SerializeTpXml<List<MyClass>>();
```

As an example of what I see in my database for the failed item:

```
<ArrayOfMyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

An example of what I see from the successful item:

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <string>192.168.1.4</string>
 <string>192.168.1.5</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

I tried serializing to XML for the benefit of viewing the data in the database, but if needed I can just convert to base64.

Any thoughts on why my custom class is not being saved? My custom class is:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public bool prop1{get;set;}
    public Nullable<System.Guid> prop2 {get;set;}
    public string prop3 {get;set;}
}
```

Note that I get no code errors - just that my xml array stored in the database is nonexistent.

Comment: Post your custom class but most likely it's because your custom class isn't marked as serializable.

Comment: Added.  Wish there was an easy way to debug this.

Comment: As an aside, `StringWriter` implements the `IDisposable` interface, so your whole invocation and utilization of it should be wrapped in a `using` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your code and ran it through a unit test but it seems to serialize properly.  Here's my entire code.  Maybe looking through this will help.  Put a break on Assert.IsNotNull and you'll see that the serialization appears to be properly handled.

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class MyCustomClass
{
    public bool prop1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Guid> prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
}

using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public static class MySerializer
{
    public static string SerializeToXml<T>(this T value)
    {
        var writer = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var myCustomClasses = new List<MyCustomClass>();
        myCustomClasses.Add(new MyCustomClass { prop1 = true, prop2 = Guid.NewGuid(), prop3 = "Testing" });
        myCustomClasses.Add(new MyCustomClass { prop1 = true, prop2 = null, prop3 = "Testing2" });
        var serialized = MySerializer.SerializeToXml(myCustomClasses);
        Assert.IsNotNull(serialized);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why, but when I deleted the class, built, then put the class back, it started working again.  There might have been some remnant from other code monkeying I was doing with EF's model generation naming that could have provided some ambiguity.  All good now :)